# How to loop through files and rename them in Python

Tags: python, filesystems, directory-traversal

I have a directory of music that has album folders as well as individual songs on each level. How can I traverse all of these files that also are encoded in different formats(mp3, wav etc)? In addition is there a way I can rename them to a format that is more consistent to my liking using regular expressions?

Thanks

Comment: I usually charge money to code up something like that. Here's something similar that I wrote in perl, you can at least see the rough idea: https://github.com/eberle1080/oggsync

Comment: @Chris: ouch, 300 lines of Perl to traverse and rename files?

Comment: No, 300 lines to transcode from one format to another. Isn't this what the OP was after?

Comment: @Chris: I think you should read the question :)

Comment: Yeah, whoops. My bad. I read into that incorrectly.

Answer (score 7):

- `os.walk` to go over files in the directory and its sub-directories, recursively
- `os.rename` to rename them

The encoding of the files pays no role here, I think. You can, of course, detect their extension (use `os.path.splitext` for that) and do something based on it, but as long as you just need to rename files (i.e. manipulate their names), contents hardly matter.

Answer (score 1):

I use this piece of code in a program I wrote. I use it to get a recursive list of image files, the call pattern is something like `re.compile(r'\.(bmp|jpg|png)$', re.IGNORECASE)`. I think you get the idea.

```
def getFiles(dirname, suffixPattern=None):
        dirname=os.path.normpath(dirname)

        retDirs, retFiles=[], []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirname):
                for i in dirs:
                        retDirs.append(os.path.join(root, i))
                for i in files:
                        if suffixPattern is None or \
                           suffixPattern.search(i) is not None:
                                retFiles.append((root, i))

        return (retDirs, retFiles)
```

After you have the list, it would be easy to apply a renaming rule. `os.rename` is your friend, see http://docs.python.org/library/os.html.